# format of some dates in dataset is different, how can i change them to the same format?

Tags: python, pandas

I figure out that some of date have the different format, i find them as below:

`out = df.loc[pd.to_datetime(df['date'],format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',errors='coerce').isna(), 'date']`

`out`

```
808    2/31/2015
809    2/29/2015
810    2/29/2015
812    2/30/2015
814    2/29/2015
817    2/31/2015
818    2/30/2015
822    2/29/2015
823    2/29/2015
824    2/29/2015
825    2/29/2015
826    2/30/2015
827    2/30/2015
828    2/30/2015
832    2/30/2015
958    4/31/2015
```

*how can i fix the format in my dataset? i dont want to see any NaT in below code*

`df['date']=pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y-%d-%m %H:%M:%S',errors='ignore')`

`df['Diff']=df['date'].agg(lambda x:pd.Timestamp.now().normalize()-x)`

Comment: Do all dates invalid?

Comment: Please provide a clear concise question that includes a complete [Minimal Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example "Minimal Reproducible Example") containing both data, and code that can be copied and pasted.

Comment: I have 1054 records. I used below code to change the format to datetime ```df['date']=pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S',errors='coerce')'''   but they are still   ```object```  then i find  ```out```   now I dont know how to fix them